# Card Hangover C

Tags: c

I am trying to do this problem: http://poj.org/problem?id=1003

```
    #include <stdio.h>

    int c;
    int a = 0;
    int i;


    int main()
    {
        scanf("%.2f", &c);
        if (0.01 <= c <= 5.20){
            for (i = 1; a < c; ++i){
                a += (1/(i + 1));
            }
            printf("%d card(s)", i + 1);
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

My code isn't working? For some reason it always returns 2 card(s) no matter what I enter. Can someone find the problem?

Thanks!

Comment: This is no debugging service. And you have to provide all necessary information **in** the question.

Comment: Because `1+1=2`. Or to put it another way: `0` is less than `0.01`. Hmm, just noticed that `c` is not a `float`. I assumed it was based on the `scanf`.

Comment: Got your warning level turned up? I would expect a modern compiler to warn about the incompatible specifier and argument in your `scanf` statement.

Answer (score 1):

Problem 1: This is not how you test if a variable is between two values:

```
    if (0.01 <= c <= 5.20){
```

The correct way is

```
    if (0.01 <= c && c <= 5.20){
```

Your code is interpreted as if you'd written:

```
    if ((0.01 <= c) <= 5.20){
```

`(0.01 <= c)` will be either `0` or `1`, and both of these are less than `5.20`, so it's always true.

Problem 2: The variables `a` and `c` need to be `float`, not `int`, because `int` variables can't have fractions in them, and `%f` format in `scanf` requires that the corresponding argument be a pointer to `float`.

Comment: Hmm, I changed those, but now its not outputting anything, not even the printf. Sorry about the questions, I am pretty new to programming.